# Custom PostgreSQL Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create multiple PostgreSQL databases using Dockerfile and create a container from this image.

My sample setup looks like this:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres:11.8

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**init.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE firstdb
CREATE DATABASE seconddb
CREATE DATABASE thirddb
```

In order to build the docker image and SSH into a running container I run the following commands:

```
docker build -t postgres:v11.8 .
docker run -it postgres:v11.8 bash
```

One of the problems that I'm facing right now is the error below as soon as I try to connect using `psql -U postgres` command:

> **psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
> "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**

The second issue I have is how to make the separate lines within **init.sql** (CREATE DATABASE ) into a single line or loop?

Thanks, guys!

Comment: That `docker run` command is running `bash` _instead of_ the database server; you should be able to just remove `bash` from that command line.  You shouldn't need to get an interactive shell in the container at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but when you run your docker image only with `-it` flags that way it's not really running the PostgreSQL process. First, run your container as its should without the flags with:
`docker container run --name db <your-custom-image>:<tag>`
After that, if you want to enter the container's bash then run with `-it` flags with the correct container name (`db`).

Comment: Hi, I've tried to run your command but I got this error:
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE firstdb
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:5: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 2: CREATE DATABASE firstdb

Btw, is it possible to create a for loop that will create the databases by list/array?

Comment: First, you found your problem! there is a syntax error in your init file.